# Not able to start Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I downloaded latest version of intellij and installed it, but somehow I am not able to start it. I tried to search a lot but not able to find the solution for it. I am getting below stack trace while starting Intellij,

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.log4j.Category.getAllAppenders()" because the return value of "org.apache.log4j.Logger.getParent()" is null
    at com.aliyun.odps.studio.intellij.ide.IntellijLogger.getInstance(IntellijLogger.java:48)
    at com.aliyun.odps.studio.intellij.ide.IntellijLogger.info(IntellijLogger.java:21)
    at com.aliyun.odps.studio.component.util.DerbyDBUtil.initOptionPath(DerbyDBUtil.java:23)
    at com.aliyun.odps.studio.intellij.StudioMain.initComponent(StudioMain.java:94)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:45)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:158)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.createInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:137)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:94)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:79)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$createInitOldComponentsTask$1.invoke(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:404)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$createInitOldComponentsTask$1.invoke(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:402)
    at com.intellij.ide.bootstrap.AppServicePreloadingKt$postAppRegistered$3$1.invokeSuspend(appServicePreloading.kt:142)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:792)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:761)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:322)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.8.1+7-b1000.32 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\raj\work\software\intellij\ideaIC-2023.2.4\jbr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by a plugin you have installed. You will need to delete `plugins/odps-studio-intellij` from your [plugins directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#plugins-directory). See also this [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-326705/IDE-crash-at-com.aliyun.odps.studio.intellij.StudioMain.replaceHelpManagerIfNecessary)

Answer (score 0):

The Solutions maybe particular for every user:--

**Sol 1:** Rollback to stable version: Please uninstall intelliJ and reinstall a stable version rather than the most updated one.As you have installed a plugin which is creating this mess.

**Sol 2:** Verify your **Log4j** configuration (inside **log4j.properties** or **log4j.xml** )file.

**Sol 3:** Check your **JDK/JRE** version compatibility for your IntelliJ IDE version.